# Hibernate query cache with Spring Data JPA and Stream is not working

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, java-stream, query-cache

I'm using Hibernate query cache on my Spring Data JPA repository, and all works if I use List as return type, if I use Stream seems that hibernate not cache results:

Not working code:

```
@Query("select E from Entity E where E.id = :id E.name asc")
@QueryHints({@QueryHint(name = "org.hibernate.cacheable", value = "true")})
Stream<Entity> getProvinceList(@Param("id") String id);
```

Working code:

```
@Query("select E from Entity E where E.id = :id E.name asc")
@QueryHints({@QueryHint(name = "org.hibernate.cacheable", value = "true")})
List<Entity> getProvinceList(@Param("id") String id);
```

Closing or not the stream in the client code, makes no differences.

Anyone has the same problem? Actually I solved using list and convert it to stream in the client code.

Comment: What makes you think the query cache is not used in the stream variant?

Comment: I have write an integration test that uses com.vladmihalcea.sql.SQLStatementCountValidator to check the number of executed query.

Comment: Did you check that it is actually reissuing the query and not some other query? For example for lazy loading?

Comment: Hi Jens, yes the query is the same, is only one and there isn't lazy loading involved